# SSIS Is it a good idea to set ValidateExternalMetadata to false?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that reads from and writes to a table using OLE DB source and target. Recently we've added two new columns to the table. My SSIS package doesn't use these columns, but now I'm getting "The external columns are out of synchronization with the data source" warnings when I open the package.
I tried to run the package and it finished successfully, but I can see these warnings in the execution results. I could refresh the metadata of course, but there are many packages that are running in Production and using this table, so I don't think it's a good idea to refresh all of them and redeploy...
Is it a good idea to set ValidateExternalMetadata to false when I create a package so I won't get these warnings in the future? Any other suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ValidateExternalMetadata setting is "You can pay me now or pay me later"

A data flow must ensure the meta data it was built against remains true whenever the task runs. The SSIS designer also validates the metadata whenever the package is opened for editing.

Flipping the default setting from True to False can save you cycles during development if a participant (source/destination) is extremely complex/busy/latency-filled.

Setting this to False can also improve the start time of an SSIS package as the task will only be validated if it runs. Say you have a foreach file enumerator and it only finds a file once a quarter (but runs every day as Accounting can't quite tell you when they'll have the final numbers ready HYPOTHETICALLY SPEAKING). Since the Data Flow task will only get validated 4 out of 365.25 days, that *could* be a beneficial performance savings. Probably not much but if you're trying to eek out every last bit of performance, that's a knob you can flip.

Another coding aphorism is that "Warnings are just errors waiting to grow up." Adding columns is unlikely to grow into an error but you are now spending CPU cycles on every package execution raising and handling the OnWarning event due to mismatched meta data. If you have an ops team, they may grow complacent about warning's from SSIS packages and miss a more critical warning.

A way to avoid this in the future is to write explicit queries in your source. Currently, the SELECT * (or the underlying table as source) are reporting back the new columns which is where the impedance mismatch comes into play. If you only ever bring in the columns you asked for, adding columns won't cause this warning to surface.

Removing a column of course will flat out cause the package to fail (under either the explicit or implicit column selection approaches).